# How to pass a LESS variable into a class name

Tags: css, less

I have a LESS variable:
`@columns: 12`

I would like to pass this variable into a CSS class name ideally as:
`.one-{@columns}-inner {}`

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't parse correctly ? How are you compiling the files ? Are you getting an error ?

Comment: `.one-{@columns}-inner {}` - This won't work because there is an error and the `@` should be present outside the braces but the one in the answer should work unless you are using a very outdated compiler version.

Comment: This had been answered nicely by [pinturic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3790895/pinturic). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you can do it this way:

```
// Using variables
.one-@{columns}-inner {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and that doesn't parse correctly.

Comment: It works but unfortunately I am parsing via less.js. I guess that is the issue I am having.

Comment: It depends on the compiler version (I think it is from version 1.3 and upgraded in 1.3.1). I have tested it here and it is working: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler. Which version do you have ?

Comment: 1.1.3 ... but I have tested the solution with a grunt compiler and all was fine. Cheers.